# Does ASLR randomize .data when the binary has no PIE?

Tags: c, aslr

I've been playing with a binary programmed in C that has a buffer overflow to investigate how the different binary protections work and I've run into a situation that I can't quite figure out.
I made a small ROP chain to run execve to instance /bin/sh. The binary has **no PIE** and **no canary**, but on the host I do have **ASLR enabled**.
I'm running it in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 20.04 freshly installed.

Logically the gadget addresses are not going to be modified by ASLR, but when I write the /bin/sh string in a .data zone shouldn't this address be randomized? Doesn't ASLR randomize .data?

Right now I am able to get /bin/sh instance by hardcoding the .data address I want to write to.